# instantiating more than one object

Tags: javascript, object

in Javascript, I am creating an object like this:

```
var testObject = {
    value: "this is my initial value",
    setup: function() {
        value: "foo"
    }
};
```

Now, I would like to be able to instantiate this object, so I am trying this:

```
var myFirstObject  = new testObject();
var mySecondObject = new testObject();
```

so that when I call `.setup()` it will change the value only for that referenced newly created object. How can I achieve this? This code does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't instantiate objects, you instantiate functions.

```
var testObject = function() {
  this.value = "this is my initial value";
  this.setup = function() {
    this.value = "foo";
  }
}

var myFirstObject = new testObject();
var mySecondObject = new testObject();
```

EDIT:
As per your comment, here's how you would bind to the DOM using functions on this object:

```
document.getElementById('idOfElem').addEventListener(
    'click', myFirstObject.clickHandler);
```

Bear in mind that you won't have any guarantee that the click handler will be executed in the context of your object (i.e. in your click handler, `this` might not be your `testObject` instance). If your `clickHandler` intends to modify the object's instance variable in any way, it's better to ensure the context like so:

```
document.getElementById('el').addEventListener('click', 
    function() { 
        myObj.handleClick.apply(myObj, arguments);
    });
```

Comment: thank you. I have a small question and don't feel like opening a new question for this but, is there a way to bind DOM events to a function inside those objects? if that's not a quickie then I better open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You have numerous problems with your code. Firstly, you are trying to instantiate something, by calling a constructor function. Your `testObject` is not a function, so you'll cause a type error. You need to change `testObject` to be something along these lines:

```
var TestObject = function () {
    this.value = "this is my initial value";
};
TestObject.prototype.setup = function () {
    this.value = "foo";
};
```

Notice that I've used an uppercase `T` in that identifier... that's just best practice for a constructor function. Also notice how I've defined the `setup` method on the `prototype`. This is much more efficient than defining it as a property of the instance (with `this.setup`) since only one copy of the function needs to exist in memory.

Now that `TestObject` is a function it can be instantiated by calling it with the `new` operator:

```
var myFirstObject = new TestObject();
var mySecondObject = new TestObject();
```

When you call the `setup` method on an instance of `TestObject`, it will apply to that instance. In other words, the value of `this` inside the `setup` method will refer to the instance on which the method has been called:

```
myFirstObject.setup();
console.log(myFirstObject.value); // 'foo'
console.log(mySecondObject.value); // 'this is my initial value'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrectly defined your constructor. Try this:

```
function testObject() {
    this.value = "this is my initial value";
    this.setup = function() {
        this.value = "foo"
    }
};
```

You can then call `new testObject()`.

Answer (score 0):

The object notation your using is something you can compare with a static class.
Here is the code for what you're trying to achieve:

```
var testObject = function(val) {
    this.value = "This is my initial value",

    if (arguments[0]) {
        this.value = val;
    }
};

var first = new testObject(); //uses initial value
var second = new testObject("hi"); //value = hi
```

If you'd like to write classes using this notation take a look at this: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

```
function yourObject(value, setup) {
        return {
            value: value,
            setup: setup
        };
}

var myFirstObject = new yourObject('a', function(){});
var mySecond = new yourObject('b', function(){});
```